# Forbidden characters inside CONTAINS (Transact-SQL) statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, contains

I would like to know which characters cannot be inserted into a [CONTAINS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) statement.

For example, let's assume I have an entry in my DB with name='Jon Snow'.

Running this query I correctly get the result.

```
select name
from Userstable
where CONTAINS((name),'JON AND SNOW')
```

Running e.g.

```
select name
from Userstable
where CONTAINS((name),'JO*N AND SNOW')
```

I get 0 results (but no error, so that's OK).

Instead, running e.g.

```
select name
from Userstable
where CONTAINS((name),'J[ON AND SNOW')
```

I get syntax error.
What are the characters that give me syntax errors?

So far I found:

```
[
]
!
,
```

Thanks

Comment: Just use quotes to close the phrase you want - i.e. '"J[ON" AND "SNOW"' is fine, so is '"J*ON" AND "SNOW"'. On the top of my head you have to worry also about ( , ) and ~.

Comment: I need to find all the forbidden characters to strip them out, avoid therefore SQL syntax errors and returning results (since I stripped out the "wrong" characters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found all the forbidden characters.

```
,
'
"
~
(
)
[
]
!
```